# stop reloading the page when choosing a payment method in virtuemart checkout

Tags: javascript, virtuemart

on virtuemart checkout process, on choosing the payment method, when click on the radio button, page reloads.

i have wrote a function that does something when page reloads or refreshes.

but the function doesn't work on reloading caused by choosing the payment method.

same thing happens when clicking on confirm checkbox at the end of checkout process.

this is the function that i wrote:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    if (sessionStorage.checkoutstepHolder > 0) {
        cartButtonHandler("onLoad");
    }
});
```

i can't find the event listener that is listening to them, cause i don't know java script.

the question is, **why the function gets called on reloads caused by refreshing, but not on reloads caused by choosing the radio buttons?**